# String.Format with null format

Tags: c#, null, string.format

Can anyone explain why the following occurs:

```
String.Format(null, "foo") // Returns foo
String.Format((string)null, "foo") // Throws ArgumentNullException:
                                   // Value cannot be null. 
                                   // Parameter name: format
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its calling a different overload.

```
string.Format(null, "");  
//calls 
public static string Format(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args);
```

[MSDN Method Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) describing above.

```
string.Format((string)null, "");
//Calls (and this one throws ArgumentException)
public static string Format(string format, object arg0);
```

[MSDN Method Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) describing above.

Comment: And I guess we should toss out a reminder to pick up a copy of RedGate Reflector so looking this up is way easier. ;)

Comment: Umm... I'd much rather go look at the MSDN documents than dig into Reflector for this kind of info. Or did I miss a joke somewhere (and yes, often reflector is good, everybody should have it).

Comment: You mean Lutz Roeder's Reflector?  (I still haven't accepted the sellout)

Comment: You can also just do right click, go to definition and it has all you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Because which overloaded function is called gets determined at compile time based on the static type of the parameter:

```
String.Format(null, "foo")
```

calls [`String.Format(IFormatProvider, string, params Object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) with an empty IFormatProvider and a formatting string of "foo", which is perfectly fine.

On the other hand,

```
String.Format((string)null, "foo")
```

calls [`String.Format(string, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) with null as a formatting string, which throws an exception.